# WordPress DropDown Menu CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a custom theme for WordPress.

I developed the basic skeleton of the theme using Ian Stewart's:
[How To Create a WordPress Theme: The Ultimate WordPress Theme Tutorial](http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/)

And developed the menu CSS using:
[Create a multilevel Dropdown menu with CSS and improve it via jQuery](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery)

Both of them are nice and complete.

When I tried registering *custom menu* to the theme, the *CSS isn't functioning for me in the sub menus*.
To register custom menu, I used the following code into `header.php`:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu ( array ( 'theme_location'=>'primary', 'fallback_cb'=>'') ); ?>
```

It's functioning for me, and showing my custom menu where I designated to. But using the custom CSS, the dropdown menus (submenus) are not showing. I used `z-index` for the subsequent menus, but till they are hidden.

Please note that: the `wp_nav_menu()` is creating a tag like:

```
<ul id="menu-new-custom-menu" class="menu">
```

So, I in my CSS I replaced all `#nav` with `.menu`. But till the submenus are not visible.

Please assist me to figure out the bug of my whole bunch of coding.
**P.S.:** I'm using WP 3.4.2 with no plugin in relation to the menu. My CSS is exactly the same as the tutorial's, except the `.menu`.

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere? The answer isn't obvious from the information you've provided so far.

Comment: Could you possibly give us a link to the site/page in which you are having the problem?

Comment: [here](http://code.google.com/p/blogger-nano/downloads/list) are the necessary codes. Unfortunately the theme is not active in anywhere else. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution at last.
It's not the jQuery issue, jQuery was to animate the menu only. I found a wrong attribute in CSS, in `nano.css`:

```
#access{
    background-color: #333;
    height: 25px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

will be

```
#access{
    background-color: #333;
    height: 25px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    }
```

The `overflow:hidden` was hiding the sub-menus.

Additionally I added `z-index` to:

```
.menu li:hover ul, .menu li li:hover ul, .menu li li li:hover ul, .menu li li li li:hover ul{
display:block;
position:absolute;
z-index:5000;
}
```

for the sub-menus. Now it's working fine here.
Thanks to Amit Chowdhury, for his assistance through the bug-fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this must be your jquery issue? I checked your css and i didnt see anything wrong on it but when I check your header.php there is no jquery library and jquery custom code embedded on it.

Did you put a jquery library before your jquery codes? See below, put this in your header.php in your **head** tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script>
  function mainmenu(){
      $(" .menu ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
      $(" .menu li").hover(function(){
      $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show(400);
    },function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
 }



 $(document).ready(function(){                  
mainmenu();
 });
</script>
```